# VB script + OPEN file.html and perform "allow blocked content" auto

Tags: vbscript, wsh

When I open the file.html by `MyShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`, I also need to enable the "allow blocked content".

Is it possible to do the "allow blocked content" by VB script after VB opened the html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible for security reasons IE considers, that is something there with the browser (IE), you can not enable it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Enable Browser Extensions","yes", "REG_SZ" 
objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\iexplore.exe","00000000", "REG_DWORD"
```

Run the above VBScript.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That permission request pop up then load offline .html's in IE. Better use [HTAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in this case. They have the permission, so not necessary any special setup.